# With regards to piping commands, what are the greater than (>) and less than (<) symbols called?

Tags: pipe

On linux at least, and I think windows/dos shell too you can use `>` to "pipe" output into a file.  Something like:

```
cat myfile.txt > mightAsWellCP.txt
```

What is that piece of syntax sugar called?  This is a "pipe": `|` so what do we call the `>` and `<`  (and `<<` and `>>` while were at it.)

Comment: Redirect maybe?

Comment: @BrianAdkins write this up as an answer

Comment: "Piping" refers to using the output of one program as the input of another. `>` doesn't pipe output; it redirects it. As for what the symbols are called, I usually call them "less-than" and "greater-than", even though that's not how they're being used. (Or in print, I just call them `<` and `>`.)

Comment: @BrianAdkins is correct - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)

Comment: See [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/23408) for much more background information and detail. This is our canonical reference work.  Note that it agrees with [Keith Thompson’s comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/23408#comment569248_480599) that ``>`` and ``<`` are *not* pipes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I usually refer to all four variations (`<` `<<` `>` `>>`) as a "redirect" when speaking to folks that I know will understand.

Answer (score 29):

`>` is used to **redirect output**.

```
$ echo "hello" > file.txt
```

`<` is used to **redirect input**.

```
$ cat < file.txt
```

Output:

```
hello
```

`>>` is used to **append output to the end of the file**.

```
$ echo "world!" >> file.txt
```

Output:

```
hello
world!
```

`<<` (called "here document") is a **file literal** or **input stream literal**.

```
$ cat << EOF >> file.txt
```

Output:

```
>
```

Here you can type whatever you want and it can be multi-line. It ends when you type EOF. (We used EOF in our example but you can use something else instead.)

```
> linux
> is
> EOF
```

Output:

```
hello
world!
linux
is
```

`<<<` (called "here string") is the **same as `<<`
but takes only one "word" (i.e., string)**.

```
$ cat <<< great! >> file.txt
```

Output:

```
hello
world!
linux
is
great!
```

<s>Note that we could have used `$ cat <<< great! | tee file.txt` instead of `$ cat <<< great! >> file.txt`, but that would do something different.</s>

Answer (score 8):

They're symbols for redirection of input/output.
[Quick runthrough on the differences between the redirection syntax commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29)

Answer (score 5):

When speaking a command-line, I usually pronounce the symbols by their function.

- `>` "output to"
- `>>` "append to"
- `<` "input from"
- `|` "pipe"

So when reading your example out loud:

```
cat myfile.txt > mightAsWellCP.txt
```

I would pronounce as "cat myfile dot T X T output to might as well C P dot T X T".